# DateTimePicker To Default to Friday Of The Next Week

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

Is there a way I can default the DateTimePicker to the next Friday so it should always default too a Friday which lands on the next week.  Even if they select a Friday of the current week.
I have the following code as my attempt:  However when modifying the
`if (selectedDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Friday)` to:
`if (selectedDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)` it loops. As the below sets it to Friday it then hits the changed event and appears as a Friday so also does the `(selectedDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)` code too causes an infinite loop.

```
var dtp = pSender as DateTimePicker;
var selectedDate = dtp.Value;

if (selectedDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Friday)
{
   var offset = (int)DayOfWeek.Friday - (int)selectedDate.DayOfWeek + 7;  //Friday after current week.
   var friday = selectedDate + TimeSpan.FromDays(offset);

   dtp.Value = friday;
}
```

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of yourse it is an infinite loop if you handle the `DateTimePicker.ValueChanged` event and change the value there. You either should do that only  in the constructor of the `Form`, the [`Form_Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx) event or you have to check if it's done programmatically:

```
private bool dtpChangedManually = false;
protected void Dtp_ValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dtpChangedManually)
    {
        dtpChangedManually = false;
        return;
    }

    dtpChangedManually = true;

    var pSender = (DateTimePicker) sender;
    int daysUntilFridDay = ((int)DayOfWeek.Friday - (int)pSender.Value.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
    if(daysUntilFridDay == 0) daysUntilFridDay = 7;
    DateTime nextFriday = pSender.Value.AddDays(daysUntilFridDay);
    pSender.Value = nextFriday;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, works fine.  I've stepped through the code and can see where I went wrong.  One thing I did try was adding this to its own function and calling this function in the event.. however there was errors around the sender.  Is this not possible?

Comment: You can acess the `sender` argument only in the event, if you call a method you should pass the `DateTimePicker` or let the method just return the `DateTime`.